# ServiceStack and Stripe

Tags: servicestack, stripe-payments, servicestack-text

I'm using the ServiceStack Stripe package, but it seems the serializer for the GetStripeCustomer method doesn't parse the Subscription Status correctly.

In the JSON I can see that the Status is "past_due", but when ServiceStack converts it to StripeCollection the Status value is "Unknown".

I'm using ServiceStack.Stripe v4.0.24

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue automatically converting Stripe's Lower_Case_Enums into ServiceStack's .NET enums PascalCase naming convention which [should be resolved with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/b069f83c6626c769f2e9e070e7f51d118462aec2).

This change is available from **v4.0.37+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: So does that mean past_due should resolve to PastDue? or should it be Past_Due? *EDIT* never mind, I can see that you're removing the "_"

Comment: Also there's another issue with the StripeCustomer object, the Deliquent attribute is missing an "n" - it should be Delinquent.

Thanks for the quick response btw :)

Comment: Any chance this version will be on NuGet anytime soon?

Comment: @VictorAgung Thanks [typo fixed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/commit/78a984733b2c2b90b8dfd0cd91d72040dd227f42) Nuget releases happen every 4-6 weeks, the next one isn't due for a few weeks yet, you'll need to fetch it from MyGet if you want it beforehand.